# Why doesn't Autolayout change a views frame

Tags: swift, cocoa, autolayout, uikit, frame

I created a view in a func of its superview

```
let black = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))

black.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
black.wantsLayer = true
black.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
self.addSubview(black)

black.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
black.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
black.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 115).isActive = true
black.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 115).isActive = true

print ("origin (\(black.frame.origin.x),\(black.frame.origin.y)) size (\(black.frame.size.width),\(black.frame.size.height)) ")
```

The output is `origin(0,0)`, `size(10,10)`, these are the values the view was created with.
On screen the black view is positioned as expected `origin:(15,15)` `size:(115,115)`.

Why is the frame not updated?

Comment: It takes time for autolayout constraints to translate into frame changes -- the main thread has to update the UI with those constraints in effect -- so that print statement isn't a reliable indicator of what autolayout is doing. The easiest (kludge) solution is to stick the print in a 1-second Timer. Then you'll see that the frame is actually updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting the constraints you can update the frame of your view calling the same of layoutIfNeeded function for Cocoa:

```
black.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
```

Comment: layoutIfNeeded() doesn't exist in cocoa. layoutSubtreeIfNeeded() works. Tnx

Comment: You are right ;) You are welcome :) ! I edited the answer with the correct solution. Thanks!